# Need help for understanding the Program

Tags: java, multithreading

I learning Java using Complete reference book. I am in Multithreded Programming Concept now. Kindly help me to understand the execution steps of this program..

```
// This program is not synchronized.
class Callme {
  void call(String msg) {
    System.out.print("[" + msg);
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
  }
}

class Caller implements Runnable {
  String msg;
  Callme target;
  Thread t;

  public Caller(Callme targ, String s) {
    target = targ;
    msg = s;
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
  }

  public void run() {
    target.call(msg);
  }
}

class Synch {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Callme target = new Callme();
    Caller ob1 = new Caller(target, "Hello");
    Caller ob2 = new Caller(target, "Synchronized");
   Caller ob3 = new Caller(target, "World");

    // wait for threads to end
    try {
      ob1.t.join();
      ob2.t.join();
      ob3.t.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }
  }
}
```

I couldnt understand the logics also.

Comment: @HighCore couldnt understand your comment

Comment: @HighCore Java also supports a synchronize/wait setup, however you can also subclass the Runnable class if you choose to. Anyway, generally in Java you just use the synchronize/wait or if you're storing data, you might use a volatile variable type.

Comment: @dylanlawrence **Nowhere** near the beauty of [`async/await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) / continuation **language-level** support in C#.

Comment: Guys Kindly help me understanding the above program. I am just a beginner..

Comment: @user3203399 What exactly do you not understand? The question as it currently stands is too broad to answer sensibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Let's do a step-by-step rundown of this Code:

first, you have three classes: Callme, Caller and Synch. 
Your main method is in Synch, let's start with it.
In the main method you instantiate Callme, then create three Caller objects.
Now, let's see Caller Constructor:

```
 public Caller(Callme targ, String s) {
    target = targ;
    msg = s;
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
  }
```

you set Callme and a custom string you passed to the constructor and then  you create a new Thread, passing the Caller object you just created as argument.

When you call t.start, you just start another Thread of execution, which will run in parallel to your already running Main Thread.
                 Also, calling start internally calls the run method you have in the Caller Object you passed to the Thread constructor.
Now, your Caller Thread will run alone while you instantiated the other two Caller objects
and run the rest of the main method.
                         After instantianting three Caller Objects, the main method calls join on each Caller:

```
    try {
  ob1.t.join();
  ob2.t.join();
  ob3.t.join();
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
  System.out.println("Interrupted");
}
```

what join do is tell the Main Thread to stop execution and await for these three other threads to end execution before continuing.

Now, let's go back to the Caller run method and see what it does shall we?

Run just call the  method call on the CallMe reference you set in the constructor:

```
  void call(String msg) {
    System.out.print("[" + msg);
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
  }
```

here you print print an custom message you pass as argument and make the currrent Thread sleep for at least 1 second(it may be more time)  before printing the last bracket.

so summing up: in the main method you create three Caller objects, and each create a Callme object, and while you main method executes(until it reachs the Thread.join method that is) each Caller Thread is executing their own copies of CallMe call method();